# modal dialog issue in Angular material design

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular material for html5 mobile app development for Android.
But i have some issue with the modal dialog.

**expected behavior:**

if i open the modal dialog and click on the device 'GO' button, the modal dialog should close and the page is redirect to the another view.

**current behaviour**

modal dialog is closing but the page is not redirect to the antoher view(issue is only in mobile)

### controller

```
$scope.kycRequest = function(){
   $state.go("kycInfo");
   $mdDialog.hide();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `state.go('kycInfo`) should go in `onComplete`

```
 $mdDialog.show({
    onComplete: function(){
       $state.go("kycInfo");
 });
});
```

https://material.angularjs.org/0.9.6/#/api/material.components.dialog/service/$mdDialog

Comment: thanks gerdi, problem is we have a 'close' button at top right corner. we removed the close button and placed it at bottom ....that's it. might be it is finding the first button and doing the action.